# Vino not working after upgrading from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 17.10, vino

After upgrading from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10, vino no longer starts.

If I try to start it manually using:

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

Then it just seg faults:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling vino using apt and also done the same through the Ubuntu Software Centre (adding and removing the 'Desktop Sharing' app) - but this didn't help.

Coincidentally, when I go to the new 'Sharing' menu in settings, screen sharing is not listed at any point.

As far as I can tell, Vino doesn't seem to have any log file so I'm a little bit stumped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is vino supposed to be able to work under Wayland?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rmano for their hint about Wayland...

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856036

Apparently Vino does not run on Wayland:

*As designed vino is tied to the X server. It's not targeted for porting
to Wayland. AIUI capturing the entire screen is simply not allowed
for security reasons under wayland. Remoting functionality needs to be
implemented at a different level in the stack on Wayland (and vino
is not part of the solution at all).*

Going back to the login screen and choosing 'Gnome on Xorg' from the settings menu before logging in allows Vino to work again.

Just to mention that the same problem also seems to affect TeamViewer.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the vino server to log in remotely on Ubuntu 17.10. After entering the password, click the gear icon by the Sign In button, and select the option 'Ubuntu on Xorg'. Click the Sign In button then verify that the vino server is running.

To verify that the vino server is running, open a terminal window and type: netstat -an |grep :59

The output should look similar to this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5900                :::*                    LISTEN
```

If the vino server is not running, you can add it to the Startup Applications Preferences and reboot. Hope that helps.